# No input file specified. in Codeignitter

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I am working on a project with codeigniter. Everything is fine in my local machine. But when I upload it to my live server it show an error

```
No input file specified.
```

I dont know where is the fault.

here is my `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^134\.17\.135\.115
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/maintenance.html -f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/maintenance.enable -f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !maintenance.html
RewriteRule ^.*$ /maintenance.html [R=503,L]
ErrorDocument 503 /maintenance.html
#Header Set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-store"

RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^f/(.*)$ /$1 [L,NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php?/$0 [PT,L]
```

and in `config.php`

I set `uri_protocol` is `AUTO`

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your `.htaccess` like this.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Or this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Comment: let me try. I will update you is it working or not :)

Comment: Which is your hosting??

Comment: @NurUddin Consider accepting and upvoting the answer if it was helpful:)

Comment: I am waiting to accept. it say I have to wait 1 minuit